# Merge Jquery accordion content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following accordions which are created dynamically:

```
<div id="accordion" class="emitters head wrapper ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-sortable" role="tablist">
<div id="Test1">                    
    <h3 class="accordion-header3 accordion-content-active ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a class="accordion-expand-all" href="#">
    </a>Name: Test2</h3>                    
        <table class="table-text table-collapse ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; color: blue; display: table; height: 17px; background-color: rgba(189, 197, 205, 0.45098);" id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">                    <tbody><tr>                     <th class="table-text" style="width: 71px">ATF</th>                     
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 73px">1.1</th>                     
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 107px">2.2</th>                    
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 223px">7.53</th>                   
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 197px">16:37:31</th>                   
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 80px">37.8715</th>                     
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 78px">60.8957</th>          
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 202px">21</th>          
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 180px">ACTIVE</th>          
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 145px">35.34</th>       
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 192px">0</th>       
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 125px">27793</th>       
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 136px">0.1</th>         
        <th class="table-text" style="width: 90px">35</th>       
        </tr>        
        </tbody></table>         
        </div>
<div id="Test2">                    
    <h3 class="accordion-header3 accordion-content-active ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e">
    </span><a class="accordion-expand-all" href="#"></a>Name: Test2</h3>                    
        <table class="table-text table-collapse ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; color: darkgreen; display: none; height: 17px; background-color: rgba(189, 197, 205, 0.45098);" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">                     
            <tbody>
                <tr>                    
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 71px">11</th>                  
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 73px">11</th>                  
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 107px">11</th>                     
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 223px">2.78</th>                   
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 197px">16:37:31</th>                   
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 80px">-108.6117</th>                   
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 78px">46.6017</th>          
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 202px">CDF</th>         
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 180px">ACTIVE</th>          
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 145px">11</th>          
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 192px">0</th>       
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 125px">11</th>          
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 136px">0.1</th>         
                    <th class="table-text" style="width: 90px">11</th>       
                </tr>        
            </tbody>
        </table>         
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to merge their inner tables under one header in real time. 
What is the javascript code to merge accordion content?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi ksup, so you want the items in `div#Test1` to appear in `div#Test2`?  Or is it the other way around?

Comment: Yes, I need the table in test2 to appear below the table in test1 under the same header.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will merge the contents (table headers from `div#Test2`) into the table found inside of `div#Test1`.  It is a fairly light lift where we target the DOM elements with specific selectors.  We use the console to make certain we are targeting the right things as well as monitor the before and after effects.

The jQuery methods/Documentation used here were:

[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for iteration.

[`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to select the current DOM in our iteration and insert it **after** the last item within the target element (which in this case, was a table row).

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide DOM elements.

[jQuery Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/9gxu335h/)

```
var targetFocus = $('div#Test2').find('th');
console.log('Second TH Count: ' + targetFocus.length); //Initial Test 2 table header

targetFocus.each(function() {
  var $container = $('div#Test1').find('table:eq(0) tbody tr');
  $(this).appendTo($container);
  console.log($container.length);
});

targetFocus = $('div#Test1').find('th');
console.log('First TH Count: ' + targetFocus.length);

if ($('div#Test2').find('th').length === 0) {
  $('div#Test2').hide();
}
```

Lastly, once we know for certain that the merge was successful we can hide the emptied out table with the `.hide()` jQuery method.

```js
var targetFocus = $('div#Test2').find('th');
console.log('Second TH Count: ' + targetFocus.length); //Initial Test 2 table header

targetFocus.each(function(i) {
  var $container = $('div#Test1').find('table:eq(0) tbody tr');
  $(this).appendTo($container);
  console.log($container.length);
});

targetFocus = $('div#Test1').find('th');
console.log('First TH Count: ' + targetFocus.length);
```

```css
div#Test2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" class="emitters head wrapper ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-sortable" role="tablist">
  <div id="Test1">
    <h3 class="accordion-header3 accordion-content-active ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"
    tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a class="accordion-expand-all" href="#">
</a>Name: Test2</h3>
    <table class="table-text table-collapse ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; color: blue; display: table; height: 17px; background-color: rgba(189, 197, 205, 0.45098);"
    id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 71px">ATF</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 73px">1.1</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 107px">2.2</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 223px">7.53</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 197px">16:37:31</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 80px">37.8715</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 78px">60.8957</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 202px">21</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 180px">ACTIVE</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 145px">35.34</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 192px">0</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 125px">27793</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 136px">0.1</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 90px">35</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="Test2">
    <h3 class="accordion-header3 accordion-content-active ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e">
</span><a class="accordion-expand-all" href="#"></a>Name: Test2</h3>
    <table class="table-text table-collapse ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; color: darkgreen; display: none; height: 17px; background-color: rgba(189, 197, 205, 0.45098);"
    id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 71px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 73px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 107px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 223px">2.78</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 197px">16:37:31</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 80px">-108.6117</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 78px">46.6017</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 202px">CDF</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 180px">ACTIVE</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 145px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 192px">0</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 125px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 136px">0.1</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 90px">11</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply. For some reason it is not working for me even though there is no error message in my console. I will add that I need just to "copy" the whole table test2 to the test1 accordion as is.

Comment: One thing is that the targetFocus is getting a valid reference, but the length is 0.

Comment: I've added a link to a jsFiddle example as well as added in a snippet so you can see that the console is working.  What I think may be happening is that the code I gave is firing **before** the accordion transformation occurs.  If that is the case I can update the code, let me know.